# parse string input using sscanf iteratively

Tags: c, scanf

I've an input string consisting of space separated numbers like "12 23 34".
Output should be an array of integers.

I tried the following:

```
while (sscanf(s, "%d", &d) == 1) {
    arr[n++] = d;
}
```

But I found that since I'm not reading from file (where offsets are adjusted automatically),
I keep storing the same number in `d` everytime.

Then I tried this:

```
while (sscanf(s, "%d", &d) == 1) {
    arr[n++] = d;
    s = strchr(s, ' ');
}
```

to manually shift `s` to a new number.
Which I believe should work fine. I simply don't understand why it fails.

Comment: if it is a constant number of numbers, you can use a macthing format string - "%d %d %d". if not, you can find the next space each time, and pass is as a first paramter to `scanf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second trick should indeed work with minor modifications. See comments in the code for explanation of what needs to change:

```
while (sscanf(s, "%d", &d) == 1) {
    arr[n++] = d;
    s = strchr(s, ' ');
    // strchr returns NULL on failures. If there's no further space, break
    if (!s) break;
    // Advance one past the space that you detected, otherwise
    // the code will be finding the same space over and over again.
    s++;
}
```

A better approach to tokenizing sequences of numbers is [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/strtol.html), which helps you advance the pointer after reading the next integer:

```
while (*s) {
    arr[n++] = strtol(s, &s, 10);
}
```

Comment: What happens if s in sscanf is NULL?

Comment: @mohit I doubt that it's a defined behavior. The problem with not testing for `NULL` right away in my modification of the code is not that you pass `NULL` to `sscanf`, but that you'd compute `NULL+1` on the last line of the loop, which is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` provides an elegant answer: the `%n` conversion, which tells you how many bytes have been consumed so far.

Use it like this:

```
int pos;
while (sscanf(s, "%d%n", &d, &pos) == 1) {
    arr[n++] = d;
    s += pos;
}
```